# How to get the current status of a React-bootstrap Checkbox? (whether checked in or not)

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using [React Bootstrap Check Form](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-form-check). I am using a Form Checkbox to capture an input value. I wants to get the information about the Checkbox in a react state variables.

I expect the `e.target.value` of `onClick` shall print the current status of the checkbox , ie, whether it is on or off(whether it is checked or not). But this does not happen. When I toggle the checkbox button several times, the value of `e.target.value` remains as `on`, even when the checkbox is turned off.

```js
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Check type={"checkbox"}>
        <Form.Check.Input
          type={"checkbox"}
          defaultChecked={true}
          onClick={(e) => {
            console.log(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <Form.Check.Label>Awesome checkbox here..</Form.Check.Label>
    </Form.Check>
</Form.Group>
```

How can I get the status of whether the check box is checked in or not in the React-side logic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access checkbox value using `e.target.checked`

```
<Form.Group>
  <Form.Check type={"checkbox"}>
    <Form.Check.Input
      type={"checkbox"}
      defaultChecked={true}
      onClick={(e) => {
        console.log(e.target.checked);
      }}
    />
    <Form.Check.Label>Awesome checkbox here..</Form.Check.Label>
  </Form.Check>
</Form.Group>
```